# RegEx matching HH:MM, HH:MM:SS OR HH:MM:SS.XXX

Tags: regex, time

So far I have the following:

```
^(([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9])(:([0-5][0-9]))?([.]\d{1,3})?$
```

This matches (as expected) 23:59, 23:59:30, 23:59:34.123 or 23:59:12.1
Doesn't match 23:60, 23:59. 
But unfortunately matches 23:59.60
Any ideas how to give the finishing touches?

Comment: Why should it match `23:60`? and `23.59.` is also invalid..

Comment: @karthikmanchala I think OP means it as a good thing.

Comment: I am confused.. can you tell me what according to OP is false positive or true negatie?

Comment: @karthikmanchala I think that everything up to the "But unfortunately ..." part describes the regex working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since milliseconds are allowed only when seconds are present, you should make the optional parts for milliseconds nested inside the optional part for seconds:

```
^(([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9](?:[.]\d{1,3})?)?$
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/mI2aR7/1)

Comment: Yeah, was just about to say. OP, for constructing long RegEx patterns I find a [visualizer](https://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5E((%5B0-1%5D%5B0-9%5D)%7C(%5B2%5D%5B0-3%5D))%3A(%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D)(%3A%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D(%3F%3A%5B.%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D)%3F)%3F%24) to be invaluable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: That's what I'm looking for! I knew I was so Close. But I couldn't get the nested part doing it right. My fault! Now it seems so easy...

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `\d{1,3}` to `\d{3}` for resticting milliseconds part to `.XXX` (exactly three occurrences):

```
^(([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9])(:([0-5][0-9]))?([.]\d{3})?$
                                                              ↑
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qR1yA9/1)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. Indeed I'm trying to verify timestamps coming from very different sources. So it may look like 22:45 or 22:45:40. If milliseconds are given it could look like 23:45:20.1 or 23:45:20.099. So I can't restrict the last part to three digits. But otherwise your regex is working fine. Thank you very much for your kind support.